# Should I keep an OSGi ServiceTracker open, or close it after use?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

What is the best practice for using an OSGi `ServiceTracker` in a `BundleActivator`?  I have seen examples on the web that open a tracker in the `start` method, store it in an instance variable, and close it in the `stop` method, keeping it open for the life of the bundle.  Is this appropriate?  I have been writing code that opens the tracker whenever I need it, gets the service and uses it, then closes the tracker.  Of course, this requires storing the `BundleContext` itself in an instance variable if I want to use it at a later time.  Since I have to store one or the other, it may not make much difference which I store.

In a related question, if I do open the tracker each time I need it, is it necessary to keep it open while I am using the service that I got from it, or can I open the tracker, get the service, close the tracker, then use the service?  I see no reason that I could not close the tracker before I use the service.

Answer (score 7):

Services come and go – your responsibility as an OSGi developer is to use services only when they have been published by their bundle, and more importantly to release them when they are unpublished. If you continue using a service after it has been unpublished, you risk unpredictable errors occurring. At the very least you will cause the heap space associated with that service instance to be pinned in memory, which undermines OSGi's ability to dynamically install and uninstall bundles.

So, you ask whether you should close the ServiceTracker before using the service: my answer is **NO**. ServiceTracker acts as a "smart pointer" to the current service, and it manages all the listeners etc in order to be notified when the service goes away. If you close the tracker, then you are no longer kept up to date with the state of the service, so how do you know if it is still valid?

The ideal pattern for using a ServiceTracker -- assuming that the tracker remains open throughout -- is as follows:

```
{    
    Service svc = tracker.getService();
    svc.doSomething();
}
// 'svc' is now forgotten, and may be garbage collected
```

That is, when you call `getService()` on the tracker you obtain an instance of the actual service, but you should use it quickly and then forget it as soon as you can. You absolutely must NOT store the result of `getService()` in a field and hold on to it for a long time.

As for whether you should open and immediately close the tracker only when needed – NO, there is absolutely no need to do this. An open tracker does not consume any significant resources, it simply means it is registered as a listener so that it knows when services come and go. In fact it is inefficient to repeatedly open and close the tracker since each time you open it, it has to synch itself against the current state of the service registry. This is why the pattern you have seen in examples is usually to open the tracker during bundle activation and keep it open... it's the best pattern.

Incidentally there is also no need to explicitly close a tracker in your `BundleActivator.stop` method. All resources associated with your tracker will be automatically cleaned up when your bundle stops. The only reason to explicitly close is if you have several trackers and/or service registrations, and you want to control the order in which you clean up.

Now having said all of the above, I'm going to chuck in a hand grenade: **PLEASE STOP USING `ServiceTracker`!** It is a very low-level utility, that is only very rarely required, and then only in "plumbing" or infrastructural code. Most of your application should be built with a higher level of abstraction. I strongly recommend using Declarative Services, which is much, much easier than messing around with ServiceTrackers.

Answer (score 5):

The best practice for the Service Tracker is to use Declarative Services.

For the experts: There are some highly specialized cases where the Service Tracker is useful (and unmissable!) but if you have to ask this question then the Service Tracker is not for you. The Service Tracker is a very low level way to work with services used by middleware like Declarative Service implementations, Blueprint implementations, etc.

Comment: Nice way of putting it. "If you have to ask how to use it, you shouldn't use it." :-)

Answer (score 2):

In case you wanted to open a tracker just for a service call you do not need tracker at all. All you have to do is getting the service via bundleContext and unget it when you are done.

ServiceTracker is not only good for calling a service but you can also call waitForService method so your thread will wait until a good service is available.

In case you use a service tracker and you call getService() to get the service object every time you may not call the same service. Service Tracker tracks every service that meet the filter criteria by default so if the service you used last time is unregistered next time another service will be given to you.

If you subclass from service tracker or write a ServiceTrackerCustomizer you can catch the service tracking events. E.g. you can create a logic that you provide an own service object each time a service is registered that meets your requirements. Also you can specify which services should be tracked (you return null in addingService than that service will not be tracked).

In short:

- In case you want to call a service only once or twice (for example when your bundle starts or it stops) you can simply get a service via context and unget it
- In case you want to call a service many times during your bundle is active or you want to create custom logic based on service availability events, use a service tracker

If you choose the first option, Never keep a service object for longer period in a member variable! In case of the first option you should unget the service as soon as you do not need it anymore. It is the same with service tracker. Call each time the getService method instead of keeping it in a member variable of your class as it might be unregistered by the time you need it again.

Other OSGi experts are here at stackoverflow (people who designed OSGi) so they may give more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think *ServiceTracker* is useful for using Services both inside the method `BundleActivator.start()` and inside the method `activate()` of `Components`.

The goal to use them at initialization time is to avoid the dead-lock that could be caused when we use Services at bundles that are being initialized too.

Is it a case in which *ServiceTrackers* are recomended or is there any other better pattern based on DS for initialization time?